# iterate over rows to check if values of an array exists between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and an array like this:

```
df
x y z
1 10 1
10 20 2
20 30 3
30 40 4
40 50 5

my_array= 5 35 36 40 41 45 46 47 48
```

How could I iterate over the dataframe so that, rows will be kept if `my_array` exist between `x` and `y` . The final df would be:

```
x y z
1 10 1
30 40 4
40 50 5
```

I have tried `df=df[(my_array <= df['x']) and (df['y'] <= my_array)]`

But It gives value error; `Lengths must match to compare`.

The length my my_array is larger than number of rows. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Numpy broadcasting

```
df[((df['x'].values[:, None] <= my_array) &
    (df['y'].values[:, None] >= my_array)).any(1)]
```

---

```
    x   y  z
0   1  10  1
3  30  40  4
4  40  50  5
```

Comment: Nice answer. To note, _We recommend using `Series.array` or `Series.to_numpy()`, depending on whether you need a reference to the underlying data or a NumPy array._ instead of [`pandas.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html). In this case, `.to_numpy()`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks! Old habits die hard. In future I'll try to use `to_numpy` as much as possible. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It’s difficult to stay abreast of changing best practices.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Totally agree!

Answer (score 4):

No need to iterate, we can use numpy broadcasting (which can be memory heavy for large datasets):

```
idx = np.where(
    (df["x"].to_numpy()[:, None] <= my_array) & 
    (df["y"].to_numpy()[:, None] >= my_array)
)[0]

df.iloc[np.unique(idx)]
```

```
    x   y  z
0   1  10  1
3  30  40  4
4  40  50  5
```

Answer (score 4):

Given that `my_array` is sorted, you can use [`np.search_sorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
df[np.searchsorted(my_array, df['x']) < np.searchsorted(my_array, df['y'])]
```

Output:

```
    x   y  z
0   1  10  1
3  30  40  4
4  40  50  5
```

**Note** in the general case where `my_array` is not guaranteed to be sorted, you can replace it with `np.uniques(my_array)`.